# Flutter: Gridview list with both images and videos throwing an error

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I have no idea what this error message means:

> lib/main.dart:29:19: Error: The argument type 'Object' can't be
> assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'.
> 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> 'Widget' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' >('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
> ? Image.network('https://picsum.photos/200/300')
> ^
> Failed to compile application.

```
  body: GridView.count(
          // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
          // horizontal, this produces 2 rows.
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          // Generate 100 widgets that display their index in the List.
          children: List.generate(100, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: index % 2 == 0
                  ? Image.network('https://picsum.photos/200/300')
                  : VideoPlayerController.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4',
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
```

Comment: It means you’re passing an Object to a method that requires a Widget

Comment: what is VidePlayerController.network returning?

Comment: It is returning a video from the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using the video_player package, so keep in mind that VideoPlayerController.network returns a controller, not a Widget and that's why you are getting that error.

Documentation here: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

Long story short, you need to use a VideoPlayer instead of the VideoPlayerController, something like this:

Initialize the controller:

```
late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4')
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
        setState(() {});
      });
  }
```

using the controller to return a widget:

```
    AspectRatio(
       aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
       child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
   )
```

I would recommend you to read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped VideoPlayerController object with VideoPlayer widget. So that solved above error message. I can only see the images and no videos though.

```
child: index % 2 == 0
               ? Image.network('https://picsum.photos/200/300')
               : VideoPlayer(VideoPlayerController.network('https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4',
           ),),

         );
```